# Getting the SAME random generated value in two different locations

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two different Order forms. If one is completed and then they check out it generates only one order...

But if they select to add more products it adds another one to the form..

For the first order number I want it to be a random generated number..

But for the SECOND order number at the bottom of the code. I need it to be the same number that was generated for the first order.

How Can I do that?

```
if($row == 1) {

            $sqll = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE BubbleGum SET pendingOrders=pendingOrders + 1 WHERE Name='".$name."'");
            $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type', '$amount', '$equipment', 'THIS NUMBER NEEDS TO BE RANDOM')");

        } else {

            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Bubblegum (BrainID, name, street, city, state, zip, height, weight) VALUES ('', '$name', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$height', '$weight')");
            $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type', '$amount', '$equipment', '')");
        }


    if(isset($_SESSION['more'])) {

        $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type2', '$amount2', '$equipment2', 'THIS NUMBER NEEDS TO BE THE SAME RANDOM NUMBER AS ABOVE')");

    }
}
```

**update:**

If I do what has been suggested. Then it only adds one entry into my mysql database... It does NOT add the entry at the bottom.

```
$random = rand (1 , 10);


while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        //count rows, If exist, then username exist
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        $brain = $roww['BrainID'];
        if($row == 1) {

            $sqll = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE BubbleGum SET pendingOrders=pendingOrders + 1 WHERE Name='".$name."'");
            $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type', '$amount', '$equipment', '$random')");

        } else {

            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO BubbleGum (BrainID, name, street, city, state, zip, height, weight) VALUES ('', '$name', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$height', '$weight')");
            $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type', '$amount', '$equipment', '$random')");
        }


        if(isset($_SESSION['more'])) {

            $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type2', '$amount2', '$equipment2', '$random')");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Generate a random number and store it outside the scope of your if statement then use it in both statements.

Comment: but when I use it wouldn't it create two different random numbers?

Comment: Not if you generate the random number and store it as a variable.

Comment: What does this mean: "It does NOT add the entry at the bottom." ??

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, just generate the number outside the scope of the if statements, eg:

```
$random = rand (1 , 10);

if($row == 1) {

        $sqll = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE BubbleGum SET pendingOrders=pendingOrders + 1 WHERE Name='".$name."'");
        $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type', '$amount', '$equipment', $random)");

    } else {

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Bubblegum (BrainID, name, street, city, state, zip, height, weight) VALUES ('', '$name', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$height', '$weight')");
        $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type', '$amount', '$equipment', '')");
    }


if(isset($_SESSION['more'])) {

    $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (BrainID, name, Type, amount, equipment, orderNumber) VALUES ('$brain', '$name', '$type2', '$amount2', '$equipment2', $random)");

}
```

}